# What causes these jagged lines?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I converted some GPS point data to LineStrings and I am sometimes getting these jagged jumps in coordinates. I am pretty sure my data is correct, this anomaly is just to perfect to be wrong...

Anyone seen this before and knows what is going on?

Detail:

[image: jagged lines]

Overview:

[image: overview of the detail]

Comment: looks like your software only supports a certain number of vertices (example adobe illustrator only supports 60,000 points and returns to the first point to close a polygon)

Comment: How surprising, bad GPS data. Could it have something to do with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_geographic_data_in_China, apparently you need special permission to map China http://en.nasg.gov.cn/article/Lawsandregulations/201312/20131200005471.shtml

Comment: @MichaelStimson, lol, did not know that! But I am assuming it is not that. I got the dataset from [Microsoft - geolife](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/geolife-gps-trajectory-dataset-user-guide/) it has been used in research papers, so I can safely assume its correct. Besides I do remember seeing this kind of data behavior in an other project but, can not remember what the problem was...

Comment: It could be rendering problems (as @Mapperz said). What software did you use? Have you seen the GPS data's points?

Comment: are you sure you have the correct vertice order for your lines/geometries? 'cause it looks like your data covers the outline of an area (the polygonlike shape in the overview) and a line along the road (in that detail image)? could you just have mixed those two features together (e.g. for the creation of the polygon outline; imagine the last 100 or so points are a seperate feature for the road while the fist bunch describes the polygon)?

Comment: no, ignore that with the polygon, it's just the road, isn't it? then it seems even more like the vertex order is messed up

Comment: @ThingumaBob yes, it's a GPS track on a road. Yes, vertex order is certainly messed up. But the thing is that it's to perfectly messed up... I don't understand how the order can be switched up so regularly. Before I create the line with Java Topology Suite I order the vertex by date and then feed it to the Geometry Factory that creates a LineString for me. This LineString I convert to a Feature in GeoJSON and then display it in OpenLayers.

Comment: Does the data allow for ordering by date per user (or is that already the case)? That data is a gps track collection of many different users, isn´t it? That one-up-one-down regularity could be the result of a small time stamp shift between two different users, those two ends of the track don´t belong to each other I believe. I dare say that long track consists of even more single user's tracks than it might seem, no? The same thing occurs all around your image.

Comment: More so, each trajectory in each users trajectory folder describes a different transportaion mode of that user. Did you create a line for each? Or did you combine them in some way?

Comment: Even more so...seeing just a few of those data sets...I highly doubt that they are usable as vertices for linear features at all. There is no way for those points to relate them to individual linestrings. Or at least it would be very very nasty and never 100%...

Comment: @ThingumaBob just checked the source data again, and found the culprit. The source data is not sanitized correctly like the documentation says it should be. In the source file `/062/Trajectory/20080926000623.plt` you can see the data starting to jump between two locations at approximately line 7000.

Comment: @ThingumaBob but to get back to you, about the data not being usable. I disagree, according to the documentation, every file represents one user and one trajectory, so the data is not mixed up. Just these few exceptions that I encountered, that according to the documentation shouldn't be there. But overall the data set is very useful for creating LineStrings. Cheers!

Comment: Nice...I might have been to quick to judge, I only visualized two or three users...I do hope so, that is a very interesting dataset! Cheers to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question.
I found out that the dataset has some discrepancies in it. So far as I can tell its in the following two files. Therein you can see that at a certain point the data starts jumping between two different trajectories.

```
.../062/Trajectory/20080926000623.plt
.../062/Trajectory/20081003000004.plt
```

Although the documentation says the data has been properly sanitized, there remains some additional sanitizing to be done.